# Serve up static files without a filehandler in an mvc web api project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, iis-7.5, static-files

Is it possible to piggyback some audio files off my web api project so that I can access them without running through asp .net?

I have a Audio folder in my Content folder, and I want to access them like this:  `localhost:1234/Audio/123.ulaw`.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Answer (score -4):

you can use some static file servers like nginx, apache, boa, or even mongoose (https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for it

Comment: I'm not sure we are on the same page.  I have this installed in IIS; I would just like to serve up content on the same project without having to write code.

Comment: i provided a general answer for this question, the usual way i ask windows users to share files via webserver, if you need IIS answer, you can add corresponding tags for your question